# MySQL Count Of Field Value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL view with the fields `id` and `set`. Because it's a view, most `id`s are repeated and have duplicate entries. For example, and `id` = 120158 may have 5 rows, 3 where `set` = A and 2 where `set` = B. I want to run a query off of the view to display the number of rows each `id` has associated with its corresponding sets.
I tried:

```
SELECT `id`, 
    `set`,
    (SELECT COUNT(set)) AS `CountOfSet`
FROM `view1`
```

However, this simply returns the same view (duplicate rows still exist) with `CountOfSet` equal to 1 for every row. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be grouping your results by `id` and `set` to get the desired result:

```
SELECT `id`, `set`, COUNT(*) AS `CountOfSet` FROM `view1`
GROUP BY `id`, `set`
```

This would return the results as

```
120158 A 3
120158 B 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group your data using `GROUP BY` clause:

```
GROUP BY `id`, `set`
```

Composing all together:

```
SELECT `id`, 
`set`,
COUNT(*) AS `CountOfSet`
FROM `view1`
GROUP BY `id`, `set`
```